# Sorting a list by modifying it

Tags: python, list, sorting

Ok so I'm very new to python and my job is to sort integers in a list from least to greatest. Sounds fairly simple right? However, I must not use built-ins such as the sort() function, and I must modify the list, not make a new one (e.g pure function).

This is what I had at first:

```
lst = [-10, 5, 2, 0, 3, 6, 1, 10]

def sortlist(lst):
    old_list = lst
    new_list = []

    while old_list:
        minimum = old_list[0] 
        for i in old_list: 
            if i < minimum:
                minimum = i
        new_list.append(minimum)
        old_list.remove(minimum)    

    return new_list
```

However, with all this hard work. I noticed I did not modify it. How can I change this code so that it does modify a list, rather create a "new_list?"

Comment: You can't use built in functions but you can use append and remove? And if you HAVE TO modify the old list, why do you have new_list there?

Comment: @Joe yea, ironically we can use append and remove. Typing data_list was a mistake. I just fixed it.

Comment: @Joe I know I did not modify it. I'm trying to figure out how to modify it. If I have to modify it, then append and remove are out the question

Answer (score 0):

You should append to `new_list` not to `old_list`.
Also, the `list` argument should be `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can swap the values when they are not in the proper order, like in bubble sort (not the most efficient but it seems like it would suit):

```
my_list = [3,0,-1,4,3,6]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] < my_list[j]:
           aux = my_list[i]
           my_list[i] = my_list[j]
           my_list[j] = aux
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) is your friend. Their [Sorting Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) article lists many different ways to do it. One relatively simple one to implement is called [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Here's a literal translation into Python of one of the [optimized versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) of the algorithm which is presented in [psuedocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) in that section:

```
def bubbleSort(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    while True:
        newn = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            # if this pair is out of order
            if lst[i-1] > lst[i]:
                # swap them and remember something changed
                lst[i-1], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[i-1]
                newn = i
        n = newn
        if n == 0: break

my_list = [3, 0, -1, 4, 3, 6]
bubbleSort(my_list)
print(my_list)  # -> [0, -1, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```